# Eclipse convert to Maven project not creating a POM file

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I've converted many projects from Eclipse Mars to Maven projects so I am pretty familiar with the process but I haven't done one on my current PC and, I don't think, with Mars2.  I don't know if it's something in my environment or in Mars2 or the phase of the moon but I've tried several times today to convert a project with no luck.

I choose Configure>Convert to Maven project.  I fill in the information on the form, including group id, artifact id, version, and submit.  The process seems to work and exits normally.  The Convert to Maven project menu option is no longer there so Eclipse thinks it worked - but no pom file is created.

Any ideas about what I might be doing wrong or what might be wrong in my environment?  I'm assuming it's not a Mars2 bug.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with Eclipse 2018-12. Eclipse adds the maven nature in its .project file, but it does not create a pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

Delete the project, but don't delete the contents then:
File -> new -> project -> Maven project, 
Untick "Use default Workspace location"
Browse to your project,
next,
finish